# call service from wsdl file using jquery soap

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, wsdl

I got an WSDL file from siebel team. I need to call this service from Jquery $.soap call and parse the value.

The WSDL file content looks like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsdLocal1="http://www.siebel.com/xml/GetAccountInfoReqData" targetNamespace="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsdLocal2="http://www.siebel.com/xml/GetAccountInfoReplyData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://siebel.com/CustomUI">
      <types>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsdLocal1="http://www.siebel.com/xml/GetAccountInfoReqData" targetNamespace="http://www.siebel.com/xml/GetAccountInfoReqData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Copyright (C) 2001-2004 Siebel Systems, Inc. All rights reserved. Siebel XSD Generation</xsd:documentation>
```

And i tried with this way using Jquery soap api.. After submitting the soap service i'm getting the same wsdl file content whatever i submitted.

```js
$.soap({
     url: 'http://localhost/soap/soapservices.wsdl?',
     method: '',
     success: function(soapResponse) {},
     error: function(SOAPResponse) {}
   });
```

Is this a correct way or please give some suggestions, idea to start my work.

Comment: What is your server side language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your server side code to invoke the web service method.

**Steps**

- Initiate an AJAX request to your controller/server side method passing the arguments
- Call the web service method from your server code and return the result in JSON format
- Parse the JSON in your jQuery

Comment: Actually our application using only cliendside technologies. Jquery mobile Jquery ui javavascript.. It's for an frontend application

Comment: what else we do with this WSDL file. They told using soap service to get the values.

in this WSDL file contains SOAP address.  ------ 
<soap:address location="http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&UserName=xxxx&Password=xxxxx/>

Answer (score 0):

A `WSDL` is not an endpoint for the service calls - it describes the services (where they are and what they expect). Inside the content of the `wsdl` there should be one or more `service` tags like this:

```
<service name="GetAccountInfoService">
    <port name="GetAccountInfoPort" binding="tns:GetAccountInfoBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://example.com/accountinfo"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

In this snippet you see that the address of the service you want to call is actually `http://example.com/accountinfo`. The other parts (the `port` and `binding`) describe what the endpoint accepts/returns and how it expects you to communicate with it.